# Why is my program going from my virtual environment interpreter to a python interpreter I didnt select?

Tags: python

This is my output:

```
PS C:\Python\virtenv\Reorg> & c:/Python/virtenv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(virtenv) PS C:\Python\virtenv\Reorg>  & 'c:\Python\virtenv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\scott\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '63131' '--' 'c:\Python\virtenv\Reorg\kroll\googer.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\virtenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Why is it starting in my virtual environment
`> C:\Python\virtenv\Scripts\python.exe` and then calling module
`> C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py` ?

Comment: Apologies for the first comment - I simply misread. However, this is still not a question about Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it starting in my virtual environment

Because of this - `& c:/Python/virtenv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`

The only interpreter being ran is `c:\Python\virtenv\Scripts\python.exe`

A **module** (not an interpreter) in your vitrualenv (selenium webdriver) is running a subprocess function which is a built-in **module** in Python, which is not need installed into your virtualenv

Regarding the error itself, Selenium requires you to have some browser executable such as Chrome/Firefox, and it is possible the error is related to not being able to find those.